Argument Exception When Retrieving Navigation Properties in Blazor Server App DbContext
I'm currently developing a Blazor Server App for event planning, utilizing a code-first approach with Entity Framework Core and SQL-Edge. My ApplicationDbContext class includes a DbSet:
public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
Here's an overview of my classes:
public class Project
{    
    [Key]
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public List<Events> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> PictureIds { get; set; }
    public List<EventRegistration> Registrations { get; set; }
    public List<SingleEventDetail> AvailableEvents { get; set; }
    public List<EventInvitation> Invitations { get; set; }
}

public class SingleEventDetail
{
    [Key]
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Accomodation> Accommodations { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Transportations { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> Catering { get; set;}

}

Somehow my navigation properties aren't included when I retrieve a Project instance from my DBset. To retrieve a Project instance with its navigation properties populated, I've attempted to use eager loading in my query:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        var myProject = projectService.GetProjectWithProperties(User.Id);
    }

public async Task<Project?> GetProjectWithProperties(string? id)
{
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) return null;
var x = context.Projects
            .Include(c=>c.Events)
            .ThenInclude(d => d.AvailableEvents);

return x.Where(x => x.Id != null && x.Id.Equals(id))
            .FirstOrDefault();
}

But in the line return x.Where(x => x.Id != null && x.Id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault(); I get the following error message:
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentException
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll: 'Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String] PopulateList[String](System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String], System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String])''
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.<AddInitializeExpressions>g__CreateMemberAssignment|14_0(Expression parameter, MemberInfo memberInfo, IPropertyBase property, Expression value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.AddInitializeExpressions(HashSet`1 properties, ParameterBindingInfo bindingInfo, Expression instanceVariable, List`1 blockExpressions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.CreateMaterializeExpression(List`1 blockExpressions, ParameterExpression instanceVariable, Expression constructorExpression, HashSet`1 properties, ParameterBindingInfo bindingInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.CreateMaterializeExpression(EntityMaterializerSourceParameters parameters, Expression materializationContextExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.CreateFullMaterializeExpression(ITypeBase concreteTypeBase, ValueTuple`4 materializeExpressionContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.MaterializeEntity(StructuralTypeShaperExpression shaper, ParameterExpression materializationContextVariable, ParameterExpression concreteEntityTypeVariable, ParameterExpression instanceVariable, ParameterExpression entryVariable)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.ProcessEntityShaper(StructuralTypeShaperExpression shaper)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.EntityMaterializerInjectingExpressionVisitor.Inject(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.InjectEntityMaterializers(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache, IReadOnlyList`1& readerColumns, LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders, Int32& collectionId)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache, IReadOnlyList`1& readerColumns, LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders, Int32& collectionId)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache, IReadOnlyList`1& readerColumns, LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders, Int32& collectionId)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitShapedQuery(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at DriveSyncApp.Data.ProjectService.<GetProjectWithProperties>d__6.MoveNext()

I've also attempted lazy loading, but encountered the same error when trying to access Event.AvailableEvents.
Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

How are projects and Events related? Does it have a column ProjectId to share the relationship? Without it, Entity Framework Core does not know what the relationship is between the two objects.

There's a one-to-many relationship between Project and Events, meaning one Project can have multiple Events. I leverage Entity Framework Core's conventions to establish this relationship without explicit configuration in OnModelCreating. When EF Core generates the database schema, it automatically adds a new column called ProjectId to the Events table as a foreign key, linking each Event to its corresponding Project.

The error suggests that the problem ist related to List and IEnumarable. Why you mix them in your models?

I thought so too at first. Yet the error still persists even when replacing all IEnumerables with List entities.

The error is on the string lists.  How is say List<string> PictureIds defined?

There are two ways the string Lists are being defined: 1. Within the constructor of the corresponding class: public Event(){pictureIds= new(); } and then later on by adding elements to it: SingleEventDetail.Transportations.Add(„shuttleBus1“) or 2. By setting it equal to a local List which was populated in my UI: Project.Event.PictureIds =localPictureIds; context.SaveChangesAsync();

I'm not familiar with storing collections of strings inside entities and how that would correlate with what gets stored in a table, but EF is trying to populate those string collections and does not like them being declared as IEnumerable. Try changing them to IList<string>.  Normally for navigation properties I recommend using ICollection<TEntity> but for values rather than references it seems EF is expecting lists.

@StevePy are you recommending that I switch for instance from List to ICollection because it is a navigation property? Could you clarify the benefits and differences between using ICollection and List, or is it simply the conventional approach?

No, try changing things like IEnumerable<string> Transportations to IList<string> Transportations. The List<TEntity> for navigation properties are fine. The issue appears to be the string collections and how EF is treating those as they aren't navigation properties. How are they stored in the DB?

For this to work, I would have thought you would need a foreign key in your Events table:
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }   // added
    public List<string> PictureIds { get; set; }
    public List<EventRegistration> Registrations { get; set; }
    public List<SingleEventDetail> AvailableEvents { get; set; }
    public List<EventInvitation> Invitations { get; set; }
}


Is it really necessary to explicitly define this foreign key? I assumed that EF Core could generate it automatically. However, even though I haven't declared it in the code, a key named 'ProjectId' has been created in my Events Table in the database.
